# Installing tensorflow on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I've installed tensorflow CPU version. I'm using Windows 10 and I have AMD Radeon 8600M as my GPU. Can I install GPU version of tensorflow now? Will there be any problem? If not, where can I get instructions to install GPU version?

Comment: Kind of a broad question, so I’ll give some broad suggestions. You should be able to install tensorflow-gpu using pip install. You’ll also need CUDA (the code may run without it, but it won’t use GPU). TensorFlow has a CIFAR-10 GPU example tutorial.

Comment: See [this list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) in order to see if your GPU is supported by CUDA. You need Compute Capability of 3.0 or higher for TF to work on GPU

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics card do not support CUDA drivers without which you cannot use tensorflow on GPU. Your system will run tensorflow but only on CPU.

However you can use pytorch it is another way to similar task. PyTorch has another version called CLTorch which runs on OpenCL which runs on your graphics card.

Please follow this link for more details.
https://github.com/hughperkins/cltorch

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to see a performance gain, you should have a better GPU, and second of all, Tensorflow uses CUDA, which is only for NVidia GPUs which have CUDA Capability of 3.0 or higher. I recommend you use some cloud service such as AWS or Google Cloud if you really want to do deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an AMD GPU with TensorFlow, you can follow the instructions [here](https://developer.codeplay.com/computecppce/latest/getting-started-with-tensorflow).

However:

- The GPU you are using is not that powerful and unlikely to give you much of a performance boost
- You will need to use Linux with these instructions, although there is a Windows version of ComputeCpp it has not been tested with TensorFlow yet.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your graphic card, it has to be **nvidia**, and you have to install **cuda** version corresponding on your system and SO. Then, you have install cuDNN corresponding on the CUDA version you had installed

*Steps*:

1. Install NVIDIA 367 driver
2. Install CUDA 8.0
3. Install cuDNN 5.0
4. Reboot
5. Install tensorflow from source with bazel using the above configuration